# Can I add tikzpictures to pages included with pdfpages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages

I would like to decorate pages of some pdf documents with tikzpictures. My idea was to include them with `pdfpages`, and then draw a `tikzpicture` overlay on top of the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1]{someinputpdf}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, tikzpicture ends up at page 2 of the resulting document. Is there a way to achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the `pagecommand` option, such as

```
\includepdf[pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}]{filename}
```

Comment: Very nice. Can this option be set globally for all `\includepdf` calls?

Comment: To answer my own question: `\setkeys{pdfpages}{<options>}` makes the options global, like with `graphicx`.