# Overlay LaTeX/TeX coding easily on PDF with 300 pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, pdfpages, tikz-styles

I've been looking for a way to overlay TeX/LaTeX i.e maths language etc (everything LaTeX is designed for) onto a background document containing 310 pages combined together in a PDF file.

So far I have been eagerly under the impression it would be easy to do using `pdfpages` and once I had done this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{completenotes310pages.pdf}
$hello
$\end{document}
```

the `hello` would appear on a extra 311th page. Note: `completenotes310pages.pdf` had 310 pages.

I have noticed a person trying to do it here: [How can I superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file) but it wasn't clear if he had one PDF page or two or more in his PDF file.

I'm currently looking to install the `tikz.sty` file but can't find it. I'll keep this updated with my anticipation etc.

Comment: Should we assume that `completenotes310pages.pdf` has blank spaces where you want to put the math content? And you want to put the math content in the specific spaces using LaTeX?

Comment: yes thats correct, it is by no means a blank file, theyre notes written by a lecturer and im trying to put my own notes over them in latex you see.

Comment: so,,there is writing on each page of the pdf document but areas where i can write text and it would fit in nicely,,in other words ill be using \new line \ and \qquad alot

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file

Comment: yes it is very similar in a sense. infact im happy to go with the solution for the post providing i can get the tikz.sty or pgf style file. i just cant find it atm, erm, im just guessing there is no way to use pdfpages and overlay latex on them directly without the tikz solution then for now :)..

Answer (score 9):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

- When using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) each included page will be scaled from the source document - `completenotes310pages.pdf` in your case - to the destination document `<jobname>.pdf` unless you specify the `noautoscale` key. Even if you do not specify this, or if the pages you're importing are of the exact size that you're currently working on, once a page is full, LaTeX will ship it out, and move on to the following page. This is the case with the MWE, even though you had hoped `hello` would be printed on page 1. This leads to the following suggestion...
- You will have to include the pages on an as-needed basis in order to "pause" LaTeX momentarily and add content to the page. For example, you may have a document sequence that looks like this:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
  \begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=1-5]{completenotes310pages.pdf}% Includes pages 1-5 (no additions on these pages)
  <some stuff>
  \includepdf[pages=6]{completenotes310pages.pdf}% Includes page 6
  <some more stuff>
  \includepdf[pages=7-310]{completenotes310pages.pdf}% Includes pages 7-310 (no additions on these pages)
  \end{document}
  ```

  where `<some stuff>` and `<some more stuff>` detail your mathematical addition.
- If the original document is NOT typeset in LaTeX, and it has whitespace that is actually a picture, you may have to typeset the page in the background, before overlaying it with LaTeX mathematics. For this, I would suggest using the [`everyshi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) that provides `\AtNextShipout{...}` or the [`eso-pic` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) command `\AddToShipoutBG{...}`. Actually, I think the latter option would work better in this case. And you could switch to using the foreground or background options `...FG` or `...BG` depending on whether you're placing the math content or the page.

---

Here is a practical example illustrating some of the suggestions above:

Consider the following source document, called `source.tex` and output `source.pdf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\vspace{5cm}

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: Source document]

You'll notice the gap that requires some filling. This is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% Add pages before
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \vspace{2cm}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\Huge HERE IS SOME TEXT.}
  }
}%
\includepdf[pages=1]{source.pdf}
% Add pages after
\end{document}
```

[image: Final document]