# How to comment on a PDF in LaTeX

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a way to type notes on a PDF document. I would like to be able to include LaTeX in my notes. Is there software that does this?

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing this. From overlaying LaTeX on top of a page (which will print with the document), to adding annotations which will not print and may only be viewable in certain PDF readers. What exactly are you after here?

Comment: Both actually.  I would like to make notes on my math textbook. Most of my notes will be for self-reference only. But I would also like to know how to overlay LaTeX on a PDF.

Comment: See [Overlay LaTeX/TeX coding easily on PDF with 300 pages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27376/5764) for how to overlay LaTeX on an existing document.

Comment: See [How to annotate PDF files generated by pdflatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6306/5764) to annotate PDF files.

Comment: If it's a commercial textbook then the book may very well be write protected. Even if you can edit the book, you may not be allowed to add notes (change it).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen The PDF was generated from a DVI

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: If you want to add notes to a PDF with Adobe Reader, you _must_ create it with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: No, thats no longer true with Adobe Reader X. I already wrote comments for documents created with MS Word, LaTex and InDesign using Reader X.

Comment: @TomBombadil: Ah. I primarily use Linux, so I'm stuck with AR9.

Answer (score 6):

Just to post an answer (from Werner's comments):

To overlay LaTeX on an existing document see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/overlay-latex-tex-coding-easily-on-pdf-with-300-pages).

To annotate some PDF files created with pdflatex see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex).