# Plug-in for adding LaTeX annotations to an existing pdf?

Tags: viewers, pdfpages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file)

#### Is there a plug-in for a PDF reader (or stand-alone GUI) that would allow me to add LaTeX annotations to an existing PDF?

I would like to annotate PDFs of scientific papers written by other authors.  Often, the notes that I would like to make include maths, so being able to include LaTeX snippets in my annotations is important.

I found [Overlay LaTeX/TeX coding easily on PDF with 300 pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/overlay-latex-tex-coding-easily-on-pdf-with-300-pages), but it's not quite what I was looking for because it will tedious to move the annotations into the whitespace available.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6306/how-to-annotate-pdf-files-generated-by-pdflatex - particularly the answer that refers to a `pdfcomment` package.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks for the pointer.  I did see the pdfcomment package, but I am looking for a way to add LaTeX annotations to PDFs for which I do not have the LaTeX source code (e.g., published papers written by other authors).  So, from what I understand, I don't think `pdfcomment` will work for me.

Comment: You should also take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15314/86 For dragging annotations around, you could use the technique I put in that one with WhizzyTeX and advi.

Comment: I believe that [the answer by Martin Sharrer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15324/11002) in the thread linked by @AndrewStacey is _the_ helpful one.