# Making notes onto a pdf document

Tags: equations, pdf, notes

I have some books and `.pdf` files that I would like to make some notes (particularly adding equations with LaTeX). I have seen the following post:

[Overlay LaTeX/TeX coding easily on PDF with 300 pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27376/overlay-latex-tex-coding-easily-on-pdf-with-300-pages)

But, one thing which I am looking for a method around is that the answer posted some notes in a `.pdf` with some generous spacing. Sometimes I may not have that much space (i.e.: just adding a sample picture below - to give an idea)

[image: example]

So how could I do it without overwriting some text? For instance, in the following code:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\setlength{\parindent}{1in}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
% Add pages before
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageCenter{%
    \vspace{2cm}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{\Huge HERE IS SOME TEXT aasdfasdfadsfasd.}
  }
}%
\includepdf[pages=1]{hw1.pdf}
% Add pages after
\end{document}
```

Which creates:

[image: output]

But how would this work if I were to add multiple notes (which I would imagine to be quite messy) so is this a way to organize such that it is similar to `\pdfcomment` but still be able to type math equations (I am not fully sure about this feature so if someone could explain or provide some advice that would be great). Also, if someone could provide an example of how I could use the `pdfpages` package to write on the next line and specify how exactly to layout the box would also be nice.

Lastly, just to provide an example of what I had in mind, I was thinking of something along the lines of this

[image: application1]

which then shrinks to this when I click it

[image: application2]

But I am also open to other alternatives as well.

Comment: With `\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` you can add any box to any place, and you can decide which size and form has the added box, so what's the problem?

Comment: So how would I add a new line of notes and how exactly would I determine which place to locate the box ?  Would it be possible to get an example please, Sorry I am relatively new to this part of annotations.

Comment: @Ignasi this is the best solution, please  elaborate.

Comment: For pop-ups with LaTeX formatted text see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186/

Comment: @alexG For the answer that you posted in `tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186`, could you provide an example of using such a method on a pdf document that is already written (ie: a book or something). I seem to be having a trouble of exactly implementing it on some already finished pdf page that I dont have the .tex file to. But this is exactly what im looking for

Comment: @AlexG I would also appreciate the latter demand since I am in the same context, a non Latex pdf (a scanned one in fact).

Answer (score 3):

This is a little example with `eso-pic` using `picture` commands to place notes.

The problem about where to place notes can be solved with `grid` command from `eso-pic`. This class option draw a grid on background with enumerated units which can be used as reference. Once notes are written, `grid=false` will supres it.

`\AddToShipoutPictureFG*` is used because `pdfpages` already uses `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` for page insertion and inserted text covers added notes. With `FG` notes are written after (over) inserted page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[grid, gridcolor=red!50,subgridcolor=green!20,gridunit=pt]{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pdfpages,picture}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{3pt}  
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}
        \put(450pt,405pt){
            \makebox(0,0){%
            \fcolorbox{red}{yellow!30}{%
                \begin{minipage}{5cm}
                    This is my comment
                \end{minipage}}
            }%
        }
    }
}
\includepdf[pages=1]{blind}    

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \AtPageLowerLeft{
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{3pt}  
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{10pt}
        \put(300pt,550pt){
            \makebox(0,0){%
            \fcolorbox{blue}{red!30}{%
                \begin{minipage}{3cm}
                    This is my second comment which is longer than the first one
                \end{minipage}}
            }%
        }
    }
}
\includepdf[pages=2]{blind}      

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is very nice