# Comments/tips on a (non Latex) pdf including mathematical formulas

Tags: math-mode, pdf, comments, pdfcomment, fancytooltips

My goal :
I correct copies from students that I scan to pdf. I wish I could make the annotations on the scanned copies rather than on the physical paper. Today, I have to scan the copies again to have my annotations transferable to students by email.
Since most of the annotations are similar, I wish to have a stock of annotations I could transfer on the copies.

I went through a lot of technologies, including many "StackExchange Questions" here. I considered pdfcomment, cooltips, fancytooltips, the OCG family (ocgx, ocgp, ocg2, ...), etc. 
Two tracks attracted more specifically my attention :

- pdfcomments : I like the mouseover to see the comment, the capabillity to move the annotation around so I can have a stock on a pdf and I can copy it onto the scanned copies. This would be my choice if there was not a main drawback : it accepts only plain text when I need to use mathematical notations. (It needs selected pdf readers). Because you can move comments, you can put them on any pdf, even if it is not compiled from Latex or if you don't have the source.
- fancytooltips : I like the mouseover to see the comment, and the capability to use LaTeX mathematical formulas and images. Drawbacks : I can't move the annotation from a pdf document to the copies. (It works with very few pdf readers.) . I am not sure whether I can put tips on non Latex pdfs.

Is there a way to have pdfcomment have images/Latex mathematical formulas (or references to formulas that can show with a mouseover) ? Or is there a way to transfer fancytooltips to a non Latex pdf ? Or are there other techniques to achieve the goal ?

Comment: Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119988/pdftooltip-from-pdfcomment-package-using-latex-code-in-tooltip, perhaps?

Comment: I know of this question but : * Is it working on a non latex pdf (scanned paper for instance) ? (I guess so since it is based on pdfcomment) *does it work with maths formulas ?

Comment: Well, AlexG said so, yes, about three years ago. The scanned image is included, as far as I know, you can make an overlay with `TikZ` etc. which has your `pdfcomment` stuff, for example

Comment: Then I must try harder in this direction. You seemed to ask for the very same problem (except the non Latex pdf constraint). Did you manage to enforce the proposed solution ?

Comment: I think, I have, but actually, I didn't pursue that way shortly after that. The solution by AlexG is of course very good, anyway.

Comment: is this related ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300440/making-notes-onto-a-pdf-document/  or am i mistaken?

Comment: How do move annotations from one pdf to the other? Through the export/import of an fdf?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The most simply : by copy and paste ! And everything is transferred and works fine. That is really top, but the problem is that only plain text is allowed :(

Comment: Do you copy the whole comment or only the content? And which pdf-viewer do you use?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I select the whole comment on the first document, copy it, paste it on the destination pdf file and it's done !

Comment: @touhami thanks for the reference. The problematic is near since it is on non Latex pdf and to write maths formulas. I considered once eso-pic or pdfpage to place Latex text but there is no mouseover capabilities and the enforcement can be difficult since you have to deal directly with the coordinates, not very user-friendly. I see both as primitive layers to build something on it but not something I could readily use.

Comment: Sigh. I asked two questions and you answered only one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry ! I used PDF-X Changer Viewer or Acrobat Reader DC. Note that it works when you open both files in the same pdf reader but won't work when you cross the readers. Not a problem though.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. but I think  if you use the idea in [Ignasi answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300473/71471) you can use fancytooltips because you will have new document that is latex pdf. may be i will add an answer here

Comment: @touhami Feel free to do so ! Foreseeable advantage, we could use full Latex in the comments/tooltips. Drawbacks, are probably the lack of ergonomy (grid + coordinates, non movable) but this can be addressed in the future, no mouseover feature (which is a way to get rid of space constraint on the pdf to receive the comments), capability to build "stocks" of comments that can be copied here and there. But a working example will confirm or not those predictions.

Answer (score 4):

It is to some extend possible to add unicode chars (including math symbols) to pdfcomment if you compile with lualatex (^^^^2200 etc can be replaced by the real unicode input ∀) but annotation will imho never be able to show complex equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
  text\pdfcomment{^^^^2200 ^^^^221a a=b^^^^00b2 öäüß }
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want complex equations you could probably use stamps (or however they are called in the english version of the reader), but they have no mouse up (perhaps it could be added with javascript).

Comment: It happens that I use luaLaTeX for calculations. I can also do subscripts with this unicode solution. Thanks for this bypass that helps !

Comment: Together with a web site such as http://vikhyat.net/projects/latex_to_unicode/, it is easy to transform a Latex phrase such as "\forall\epsilon>0\exists\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{*+}|x-x_0|<\alpha\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon" into the plain text "∀∊>0∃α∈ℝ*⁺|x-x₀|<α⇒|f(x)-f(x₀)|<∊" which is already useful. This transformation can probably be internalized with luaLatex code. Of course, as soon as you need to place text somewhere around such as in a fraction, in a limit, in a ∑, it is less convincing ; example : \frac{1}{x+1} gives (1/x+1).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution.

**Note:** This is not about using [fancytooltips](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) but how adding elements to a non latex pdf file, named here `mytest.pdf` and included implicitly with `mtpage` environment. (if i understand)

**Note** the example use `\usepackage[filename=tooltipy,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}`  from [fancytooltips](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) documentation examples.

The environment `mtpage` include the page of number (its argument) using `tikzpicture` inside it you can add stuff using `\mtadd` command.

The command `\mtadd[options passed to tikz node]{(x,y)}{stuff}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[filename=tooltipy,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}% from fancytooltips examples directory
\usepackage{tikz}


\iftrue % comment for final
%\iffalse % uncomment this line for final
\newenvironment{mtpage}[1]{% #1 included page's number, 
% one can do this with stepcounter  
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmaxstep{\paperwidth/.5cm}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\ymaxstep{\paperheight/.5cm}%
    \node[anchor=south west] at
        (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[page=#1] {mytest.pdf}};
    \draw[blue!20!white, thin, shift={(current page.south west)}]
        (current page.south west) grid [ystep=.5cm,xstep=.5cm] (current page.north east);
    \foreach \step [evaluate=\step as \x using \step*.5] in {1,2,...,\xmaxstep} {
    \node[xshift=\step cm, yshift=1cm] at (current page.south west) {\step};};
    \foreach \step [evaluate=\step as \y using \step*.5] in {2,...,\ymaxstep} {
    \node[yshift=\step cm, xshift=1cm] at (current page.south west) {\step};};}{%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\else
\newenvironment{mtpage}[1]{%
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=south west] at
        (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[page=#1] {mytest.pdf}};}{%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\fi
\newcommand{\mtadd}[3][text=red]{\draw[shift={(current page.south west)}] #2 node[#1] {#3};}

\begin{document}
\begin{mtpage}{1}%this is page 1
\mtadd[text=blue,fill=red!20, anchor= south west]{(6,23)}{Some text just for \tooltip{test}{1}.}
\mtadd{(13.5,18.5)}{\tooltip{bla}{1}.}
\mtadd{(16,14)}{\tooltip{foo}{1}.}
% text add no tooltips
\mtadd{(2,9.5)}{MT}
\mtadd[text=blue]{(3,9.5)}{MT}
\end{mtpage}

%\begin{mtpage}{2} %this is page 2
%\end{mtpage}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]