# Annotation on a pdf : copyable, moveable, and including LaTeX maths

Tags: pdf, annotations

My need:
As a teacher, regularly I need to annotate a pdf document of around hundreds of pages of maths. I need to be able to write maths myself in these annotations. Annotations tend to be "always the same" that is with around twenty to thirty annotations cover 90% of the needs. Therefore I build a list of annotations on a separate pdf, from which I select, paste and move around afterwards on the main pdf.

The present (unsatisfactory) solution:
I create a list of pdfcomments in a separate document and paste, move and possibly edit them in the pdf pages.

Problems:

1. not all pdf reader render the comments, but I can cope with that by selecting the reader to be used
2. I cannot write comments containing maths. I don't understand why, despite being in LaTeX, the math signs/operations are not taken into account. I use an HTML page that translate Latex to Unicode to cope with that but it is not satisfactory: long and for instance `\frac{}{}` is not well rendered.

(Some) PDF readers are capable of copying and moving comments around to find their place (through PDFcomment) . It is possible to have PDF comments including LaTeX math expression.

Question:
Is there a way to mix both capabilities in the same comment ? LaTeX package(s) would be great or any other way is welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by 'being in LaTeX'? What's in LaTeX?

Comment: Didn't you ask this already last year: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301189/comments-tips-on-a-non-latex-pdf-including-mathematical-formulas

Comment: @cfr "being in LaTeX" : I mean even if the macro is in LaTeX, \pdfcomment{$\frac{1}{2}$} Don't work !  won't show in the comment $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer,JPi : you are right, I almost forget this, sorry. I didn't find it it again when I returned to this problematic.