# How the pdfcomment package produces nice copyable moveable pdf annotations and why it cannot be a Latex maths formula

Tags: pdf, pdfcomment, annotations

Unsuccessful with a global question [Annotation on a pdf : copyable, moveable, and including LaTeX maths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374461/annotation-on-a-pdf-copyable-moveable-and-including-latex-maths) and [Comments/tips on a (non Latex) pdf including mathematical formulas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301189/comments-tips-on-a-non-latex-pdf-including-mathematical-formulas), I come back with very precise questions :

1. What is the (pdf) nature of the nice copyable and moveable "notes" pdfcomment is producing ? annotation ? another pdf object ?
2. What is the secret of pdfcomment (the LaTeX macro used by pdfcomment) to produce those copyable and moveable pdf objects ?
3. Is there a way to compile a LaTeX macro (e.g. \frac{1}{2}) to be put in the pdfcomment comment/annotation ?

Comment: Would be much more useful to link directly to your earlier asking of the same question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301189/comments-tips-on-a-non-latex-pdf-including-mathematical-formulas.

Comment: @cfr : meta : I am quite desperate with the redaction of these questions ! I try hard to be precise but failed. The question I referred to was considered duplicate with the question you quote but I don't consider it duplicate : as a proof, the solution proposed for the question you quoted is not a solution of the question I quoted. The key difference stands in the "copyable" and "moveable" properties.

Comment: meta :  Is there a place, forum for instance, to help write a good question when the question is difficult ?

Comment: Your questions haven't been redacted. (Questions can't be redacted as far as I know, except in the sense that people could edit them to remove parts. I suppose they could leave XXXX or something instead. Never seen it, though.) Both questions talk about copying and moving comments, so I don't see the difference you're referring to. But one reason the question I linked is more likely to be useful is just that there's a lot more background there in terms of solutions and discussion. By the way, your link goes to the version history page and not the question itself.

Comment: by "redaction" I meant my own writing of the question, not some editing by other as you seem to refer to (English is not my mother language so I may have misused "redaction"). I included the other question as suggested.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think there's a misunderstanding. Usually 'redact' means removing or obscuring parts of a text. For example, the government might black out people's names before releasing a document publicly, to protect individuals. Or an official might black out part of a soldier's letter home, to avoid details of military operations being made public. Or a newspaper might leave blank space to show that a story had been banned by a censor. I think you probably mean something else ....

Answer (score 7):

`pdfcomment` offers an interface to PDF annotations (section 8.4, page 604 in [PDF Reference, sixth edition ,Adobe® Portable Document Format, Version 1.7, November 2006, Adobe Systems Incorporated](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf))

There's no secret, `pdfcomment` just uses `pdflatex`'s `\pdfannot` `primitive`. It takes care of the 'over head' and `pdfcomment` just adds some meat to the bone, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\pc@annot@markup@pdf}%
{%
  \pdfannot width 0pt height 0pt depth 0pt%
  {%
    /Subtype /\pc@lopt@markup\space%
    /C [\pc@hyenc@color]\space%
    \pc@lopt@cdate\space%
    /CA \pc@lopt@opacity\space%
    /T (\pc@pdfenc@author)\space%
    /Subj (\pc@pdfenc@subject)\space%
    /Contents (\pc@pdfenc@contents)\space%
    /Open \pc@lopt@open\space%
    /QuadPoints [\pc@annot@quadpoints]\space%
    /F 4\space%
  }%
}%
```

Other `engines` need different approaches like `\special{pdf: ann width 0pt height 0pt depth 0pt%` (dvipdfmx) or `\pdfmark[\rule{0pt}{0pt}]%` (dvips).

You can not really add a `LaTeX` macro like `\frac{1}{2}` into a `\pdfcomment` macro, as the standard text `PDF` annotations (there are also others like audio annotations, stamps, ...) are designed as 'text only' in the `PDF` format by Adobe. You may add some mathematical symbols and so on in `Unicode`

For complex material you need a completly different approach like `fancytooltip` or `AlexG`'s hacking in `Javascript`, see e.g. [Move-around box in PDF display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107247/move-around-box-in-pdf-display/108998#108998)

Comment: To keep the essential moveable/copyable property, I used Unicode characters within the pdfcomment macro as indicated. In fact, I write the Latex phrase I need and then I use a [Latex to Unicode online engine](http://vikhyat.net/projects/latex_to_unicode/) to produce the Unicode sequence. Workable.

Comment: What is the nature of LaTeX maths formulaes as seen by the pdf document ? An image ? Created by pdflatex for instance ?

Comment: Since it seems that all unicode characters are OK with the pdf definition of "text only", can we imagine to use the "unicode-math" package together with Lualatex to produce the Unicode sequence from a standard LaTeX maths formula ?  I tried, but it failed with a "! Improper alphabetic constant" error.