# pdfcomment math style

Tags: beamer, math-mode, pdfcomment

I'm making a presentation and want to insert a comment, like a pop up comment, which contains some equations in math style. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

  go back to the last equation. \pdfcomment{$x^{2}+2x-1=0$ }

\end{document}
```

My problem is that the equation above doesn't appear in the math style
 $ x^{2}+2x-1=0.$

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: classic PDF annotations are text only! In this simple case you can input the equation as Unicode *text*! see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301189/comments-tips-on-a-non-latex-pdf-including-mathematical-formulas/301265#301265

Comment: @John If you look for something more fancy, see this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186