# Why the measurement of vertical distance between two points is wrong?

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

Please, 
consider the following (not so minimal) MWE. Why the distance between points named `a3` and `b3` is not the same as the vertical distance between points `a2` and `b2` (it is about 30% larger)? From my code follows, that `b3` is for vertical distance between `a2` and`b2` right from `a3`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,
               tikz,%class=zfc-book2b,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,positioning}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
        \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
X/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
   every   pin/.style  = {inner sep=1pt, align=center,
                          font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                          pin edge={<-,solid,black,shorten <=1pt}
                          }
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[yshift=20mm]
\draw[red,thick]
    (-2.2,-1) -- (-1.5,-1.0) coordinate[pin=120:a1] (a1)
              |- (-0.5,-0.5) coordinate[pin=120:b1] (b1)
              |- ( 0.5, 0.0) 
              |- (1.5,0.5) |- (2.2,1);
%--- axis
\draw[->]   (-2.2,0) -- (2.4,0) node[below left] {$V_i$};
\draw[->]   (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.7) node[below left] {$q(t),\ V_o$};
    \end{scope}
\draw[red,thick,name path=A]
    plot[domain=0:120, samples=59]  ({2*sin(\x+120)},-2+\x/60);
\draw[->]   (-2.2,0) -- (2.4,0) node[above left] {$x(t)$};
\draw[->]   (0, 0.1) -- (0,-2)  node[above left] {$t$};
    \begin{scope}[yshift=20mm,xshift=40mm]
\draw[->]   (-1.2,0) -- (4.4,0) node[below left] {$t$};
\draw[->]   (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.7) node[below left] {$x_q(t)$};
    \end{scope}
\coordinate             (a3)    at (4.5,2);
    \path[name path=B]  (a1) -- + (0,-2.5);
    \path[name path=C]  (b1) -- + (0,-3.0);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=A and B, by=a2}];
\coordinate[name intersections={of=A and C, by=b2}];
\path   let \p1 = (a2),
            \p2 = (b2),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\y2)} in
        coordinate[right=\n1 of a3] (b3);
\draw[->,dashed]    
    (a1) -- (a2) node[X,pin=240:a2] {} -| (a3) node[X,pin=90:a3] {};
\draw[->,dashed]    
    (b1) -- (b2) node[X,pin=240:b2] {} -| (b3) node[X,pin=90:b3] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
```

I gave my best to write above code in accordance with instructions in TikZ manual as well as in similar question on SE, however the result is not as expected. I give up in searching what is wrong in above MWE ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it helps to replace

```
\path   let \p1 = (a2),
            \p2 = (b2),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\y2)} in
        coordinate[right=\n1 of a3] (b3);
```

by

```
\path   let \p1 = (a2),
            \p2 = (b2),
            \n1 = {\y1 - \y2} in
        coordinate[right=\n1 of a3] (b3);
```

? `veclen()` is useful for 2D vectors, but you just want the difference between two y coordinates.

[image: result]

With [screen ruler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29331/38080):

[image: result with screen ruler]

Comment: I nowhere see this possibility for calculation of lengths ... and it works! Thank you for help

Comment: +1 and works, although it's quite surprising... I expected the same result.

Comment: @Rmano thanks for the ruler! Just another suggestion, matching the topic of confusing coordinate calculations: `\draw[blue] let \p a = (a2 -| a3), \p b = (b2 -| b3) in (\p a) circle[radius=\x b - \x a];`