# adding text onto pdf pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages

This is related to the post [How can I superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file).

One of the answers is (which is the one I'm using now):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]\node at (current page.center) {overlayed text};\end{tikzpicture}}]{filename}
\end{document}
```

I modified is to use absolute position:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]\node at (0.5, 1) {overlayed text};\end{tikzpicture}}]{filename}
\end{document}
```

However when I tried it on a pdf document with multiple pages, only the *first* page of the  pdf document is extracted and used for the creation of the new pdf document. The text *is* included the new pdf correctly.

Question: How do I make sure that the text is included on every page?

Answer (score 6):

Easy fix:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \node at (0.5, 1) {overlayed text};
    \end{tikzpicture}}]{filename}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So the fix consists in adding the option `pages=-` to `\includepdf`. A little more verbosity is usually helpful.