# Embedding PDF while rewriting fonts in Latex

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdf, miktex, texify

I have some PDF-files which I embed as graphic-objects into my latex-project. Those PDFs come from different sources. One I created in Powerpoint myself, then exported to PDF to make it vectorized and another one is cropped from a PDF usermanual.

Now I'm wondering what would be the best and easiest way (if there is one) to embed those PDFs into my latex document but somehow make the fonts in it being compiled by texify so that the fonts look the same as in my project. I assume there's a function to maybe put some "placeholders" into the pdf's I'd like to embed and replace them at compiling-time by some texts in the correct latex-font!?

Thanks in advance

**Okay to clarify**: I have a PDF with vectorized figures in it and texts on the axis, a title and so on... I'm looking for ANY way to embed this PDF into my latex document with rewriting the texts in the PDF in the font being used in my latex document so that the ensemble looks nice.

**My first edit was (which works by manually using the `overpic`-package)**: Manually doing it works like this:
1. Open the PDF in any PDF-editor and delete all the text-objects (so that only the graphical part remains in the PDF), save it
2. Include the PDF in your latex document using the `overpic`-package with the rgid option
3. Now put texts (or even math-formulas possible) OVER the embedded graphical object (which comes from the PDF-file). The texts will therefore obviously look like any other text in your document (similar in style / font etc.)
(Some more informations on overpic: [How can I superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a PDF file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file))

**EDIT2**: As stated below in the comment:
If you put this out of hold, I'll post my own answer as solution to the question below which would, as you say Charles, be worth mentioning just to record the solution which is really a nice one. Easy to do and very very nice in the final output.

Comment: No, you can't replace the fonts of included PDFs.

Comment: Okay I found an answer myself... thanks for putting it on hold without any real reason, that must have got to do anything with profile neurosis of the admins here...! But to state the solution: Open the pdf file in inkscape (free) and export it to pdf with the option to exclude fonts in the pdf file while generating an addition tex-file (which will then hold the texts). So it works nicely...

Comment: Putting a question "on hold" just mean the community does not really get your question, and that we are waiting for you to clarify it before we can answer. Once you clarify it, the question would be reopened. I don't even really understand your own answer… what I would have suggested (and what I think you did) is crop the PDFs and rewrite the text in TeX.

Comment: @ienissei - If I understand the Inkscape feature, it strips all text objects from the PDF without cropping.

Comment: bjoern: Sorry it is somewhat bureaucratic, but this is the way we have learned to work with the site's tools.  Could you pare down your post to a clear qn - your answer is well worth documenting?

Comment: @ienissei No answer/comment doesn't always mean that it's not understandable (obviously, Martin Schröder and Charles Stewart) did - it _can_ also mean that simply nobody knows a solution to it which is not a reason to put it on hold. But if that's the standard the network refers to, okay, then it should be like it. And yes Charles got me right. Inkscape can strip all texts from the PDF which will result in a PDF only containing vectorized graphics without any sort of text in it. But besides that Inkscape also generates a tex-file automatically which you then can include into your latex-doc

Comment: and it will then display the texts via \put{} over the vectorized graphic (which was output as PDF). By using this I get a nice looking figure (vectorized pdf) in my latex document as well as the texts being written in my latex-font (because of the usage of the \put-command).

Comment: If you put this out of hold, I'll post my own answer as solution to the question below which would, as you say, be worth mentioning for the community...

Comment: For the PDF you create yourself the best way would consist in using the same font (there are fonts provided in both Type1 and True-/Opentype) for creation – or at least a very similar one.

Comment: Actually I don't like this approach since I never know in advance which scaling I'll use in the latex-document for the PDF and therefore it's not too nice as the fonts will also resize (get smaller and bigger :() -> it's really better using the overpic or inkscape approach as the font's won't get resized when scaling the figure.

Comment: Björn, was ist los? Du wolltest, dass die Frage wieder geöffnet wird, weil Du unbedingt eine Antwort schreiben wolltest. Und nun – wo bleibt sie? Ich denke nämlich, dass sie interessant und für andere hilfreich sein dürfte.