# Superimpose LaTeX / TeX output over a large PDF file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, pdfpages

I need to add annotations to large PDF file. The method suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326202/37321) does not scale well:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pagecommand=
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node at (current page.center) {overlayed text};
 \end{tikzpicture}},pages=1]{filename.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=2-]{filename.pdf}
\end{document}
```

My PDF file is 700 pages long. I annotate the file at random pages (50+ annotations). Now my source has the following structure:

annotationion of page X

`\includepdf[pages=(X+1)-(Y-1)]{filename.pdf}`

annotationion of page Y

`\includepdf[pages=(Y+1)-(Z-1)]{filename.pdf}`

annotationion of page Z

The extra `\includepdf` are both annoying and error prone. Is there a way to automate this procedure?

Comment: For the future casual reader: if you just need to overlay text, `tikz` is overkill. You are better off with `textpos`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update: Package now released on CTAN

I finally got around to tidying up my `pdfoverlay` package and releasing it on to CTAN. It's also in TeXLive and MikTeX. See https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfoverlay.

I re-implemented it in `expl3` and wrote some proper documentation. The syntax is slightly different taking into account some of the feedback from the comments below.

The MWE example below now becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfoverlay}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{filename.pdf}
\begin{document}
Annotation on page 1.
\pdfoverlayIncludeToPage{10}
Annotation on page 10.
\pdfoverlayIncludeToPage{50}
Annotation on page 50.
\pdfoverlayIncludeToLastPage
\end{document}
```

---

## Original Answer

I have written a package that is exactly for this kind of thing. It's not documented except with a few comments and isn't in CTAN. (I could add it, though not for a couple of weeks.) It probably also needs some error checking to be a bit more robust.

It allows for this kind of thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfoverlay}
\pdfoverlaySetPDF{filename.pdf}
\begin{document}
Annotation on page 1.
\pdfoverlayMoveToPage{10}
Annotation on page 10.
\pdfoverlayMoveToPage{50}
Annotation on page 50.
\pdfoverlayMoveToLastPage
\end{document}
```

Just save this as `pdfoverlay.sty` and put it in the same directory as your `tex` file.

```
%%
%% This file is pdfoverlay.sty'
%% 
%% Copyright (c) 2017-2018
%% by David Purton <dcpurton@marshwiggle.net>
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions of
%% the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c of this license
%% or (at your option) any later version. The latest version of this
%% license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This work is "maintained" (as per the LPPL maintenance status)
%% by David Purton.
%% 
%% This work consists of the file pdfoverlay.sty.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{pdfoverlay}
  [2018/04/04 Package for overlaying text on an existing PDF document (DCP)]

\RequirePackage{everypage}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{pdfoverlay@page}

\newtoggle{pdfoverlay@outputpage}
\toggletrue{pdfoverlay@outputpage}

\newcommand{\pdfoverlay@setpdf}{%
  \iftoggle{pdfoverlay@outputpage}
    {\ifcsvoid{pdfoverlay@pdf}
      {\PackageError{pdfoverlay}
         {No PDF file set}
         {Set a PDF file using \protect\pdfoverlaySetPDF}}
      {\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
         \ifnum \thepdfoverlay@page>\z@
           \unless\ifnum \thepdfoverlay@page>\pdfoverlay@pagecount
             \includegraphics[page=\thepdfoverlay@page,
                              width=\paperwidth,
                              height=\paperheight]{\pdfoverlay@pdf}%
           \fi
         \fi}}%
       \stepcounter{pdfoverlay@page}}
    {}}

\def\pdfoverlay@pdf{}

% set the PDF to output in the background
% \pdfoverlaySetPDF{filename.pdf}
\newcommand{\pdfoverlaySetPDF}[1]{%
  \IfFileExists{#1}
    {\gdef\pdfoverlay@pdf{#1}%
     \edef\AM@currentdocname{#1}%
     \AM@getpagecount
     \xdef\pdfoverlay@pagecount{\AM@pagecount}}
    {\PackageError{pdfoverlay}
       {PDF file #1 not found}
       {}}}

\setcounter{pdfoverlay@page}{0}%
\AddEverypageHook{\pdfoverlay@setpdf}

% jump to page in background PDF without outputting pages in between
% \pdfovrlaySetPage{n}
% where n is an integer
% NOTE: The page will not actually be outputted
%       unless there is some text overlayed on it
\newcommand{\pdfoverlaySetPage}[1]{%
  \setcounter{pdfoverlay@page}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{pdfoverlay@page}{-1}}

% Move through the PDF to the specified page
% \pdfoverlayMoveToPage{n}
% where n is an integer
% NOTE: The page will not actually be outputted
%       unless there is some text overlayed on it
\newcommand{\pdfoverlayMoveToPage}[1]{%
  \whileboolexpr
    {test {\ifnumcomp{\value{pdfoverlay@page}}<{#1-1}}}
    {\null
     \clearpage}}

% Move through the PDF to the last page
% NOTE: Any further text will be output on the next page
\newcommand{\pdfoverlayMoveToLastPage}{%
  \whileboolexpr
    {test {\ifnumcomp{\value{pdfoverlay@page}}<{\pdfoverlay@pagecount-1}}}
    {\null
     \clearpage}%
   \null}

% Toggle outputting the PDF
\newcommand{\pdfoverlayOutputToggle}{%
  \iftoggle{pdfoverlay@outputpage}
    {\togglefalse{pdfoverlay@outputpage}}
    {\toggletrue{pdfoverlay@outputpage}}}

% Resume outputting the PDF
\newcommand{\pdfoverlayOutputToggleTrue}{%
  \toggletrue{pdfoverlay@outputpage}}

% Pause outputting the PDF
\newcommand{\pdfoverlayOutputToggleFalse}{%
  \togglefalse{pdfoverlay@outputpage}}

% Set page style to empty
\pagestyle{empty}

\endinput
```

Comment: It works very well!

Comment: I tested your package for a couple of days. It works smoothly. A minor comment if you decide to put it on CTAN. Adding `\setcounter{page}{#1}` to the definition of `\pdfoverlaySetPage` helps when you skip many pages of the original file (requires `hyperref`).

Comment: An even lesser comment: I find the names `\pdfoverlaySetPage` and `\pdfoverlayMoveToPage` counter-intuitive. What you really mean is`\pdfoverlaySkipToPage` and `\pdfoverlayIncludeUptoPage` or something like that.

Comment: @david-purton, If you are indeed the creator of pdfoverlay, first, thank you. Secondly there's a question I could use your help for here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615617/picture-bugs-using-pdfoverlay

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your statement about scalability refers only to the fact that it is tedious and error prone to do it by hand and *not* to the efficiency on large pdf files, I propose you an idea that can be used to implement your own commands for your specific case.

In words, it is about taking advantage of a counter to keep track of which page was annotated and build a command that make an annotation on a given page, printing all the previous not annotated ones.

**Disadvantage:** You have to put the `\makeAnnotation` commands in order (with respect to the annotated page), but it should not be a big deal and I think you will do it anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{PageOfPdf}

\newcommand{\makeAnnotation}[1]{%
    \ifnumequal{#1}{1}{}{%
        \stepcounter{PageOfPdf}%
        \ifnumequal{#1}{\thePageOfPdf}{}{
            \thePageOfPdf-\the\numexpr #1-1 \\
        }
    }%
    annotate on #1 \\
    \addtocounter{PageOfPdf}{\numexpr #1-\thePageOfPdf}
}
\newcommand{\lastAnnotation}[1]{%
    \makeAnnotation{#1}
    {\the\numexpr #1 +1}- \\
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \makeAnnotation{1}
    \makeAnnotation{11}
    \makeAnnotation{12}
    \lastAnnotation{16}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Few additional remarks:

- The external `if` clause in the `\makeAnnotation` command is necessary in case you need to annotate the first page of your pdf file
- The internal `if` clause, instead, is needed to avoid to print the range of unannotated pdf pages in case two following annotations are on consecutive pages
- The `\lastAnnotation` command should print the remaining bunch of pages

And few more remarks:

- Here I added later the `etoolbox` package for the `if` clauses; it is very powerful and it could be used to improve the code
- It could be that there are additional cases I did not consider, but the main idea is here and you should be able to cope with them in case
- Better ideas/approaches probably exist and feel free to suggest them :)