# Picture bugs using pdfoverlay

Tags: graphics, pdf

I am using pdfoverlay to write over an orignal document, but it seems that it has an influence on the pictures inside the original like so :

[image]

as you can see, some white rectangles appeared (or where displaced)

Here is my code :

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{pdfoverlay}
    \pdfoverlaySetPDF{PSI-CCINP-2021.pdf}
    
    \begin{document}
    \pdfoverlayIncludeToPage{13}
    \end{document}
```

Here is a link to my overleaf project if you want the original pdf:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/gtwzzfrqwgvf

Not all PDF readers seem to see the problem (overleaf's one doesn't), but the one I use (mac-os original one) and my printer see those white spots.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem as I don't use MacOS, but I doubt that `pdfoverlay` is the problem. Underneath `pdfoverlay` just uses `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.AcrobatPro does identify a syntax issue of some kind with the original PDF.

Comment: What do you get if you bypass `pdfoverlay`:
`\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight){\includegraphics[page=8,width=\paperwidth]{PSI-CCINP-2021.pdf}}}\begin{document}\null\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidPurton , thank you for your help, I tried the code you gave, but it compiles with errors, and the output is a three page document, where the first page is empty, on the second, the page 8 of the original is present but largely offset to the right (visible if you use the link in the question), and a third page empty as well.
*changing the values in \put() doesn't help.

Comment: And when I take the document out of overleaf it's even worse, the picture of the robot is just the G point on white background

Comment: The code in my comment doesn't work on Overleaf, because Overleaf's version of TeXLive is too old. And probably your offline version needs updating too.

Comment: To test with overleaf, you can try this code:
`\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{eso-pic}\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageCenter{\makebox(0,0){\includegraphics[page=8,width=\paperwidth]{PSI-CCINP-2021}}}}\begin{document}\null\end{document}` This compiles on Overleaf with TeXLive 2020. But it will not work on a fully updated TeXLive system. This is basically what `pdfoverlay` is doing on Overleaf.

Comment: Actually the code in previous comment will work in latest TeXLive. `eso-pic` was updated. But the version of `pdfoverlay` in Overleaf definitely won't. You need the latest version which is 1.2a.

Comment: @DavidPurton , thanks again, this second code does give a one page pdf containing the 8th page of the original, but it has the same problem I depicted in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129748/discussion-between-lmt-phd-and-david-purton).