# I have a pdf (which was created in latex). Is there a way to turn it back to latex?

Tags: pdftex

*I have a pdf (which was created in latex). Is there a way to turn it back to latex?

*Another question, is there a way to add latex notes to a pdf?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  I don't think you can recover the original LaTeX code from the pdf unless it was imbedded in it. For adding notes, see the `todonotes` package. Theoretically it should be possible to convert the pdf to TeX but doing that for the general case is a pretty big undertaking.

Comment: Welcome to TeX! I suggest to google for "conversion pdf to latex". You may find sites like [https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/pdf-to-tex](https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/pdf-to-tex). Because of the difference in abstraction level (PDF: single characters positioned on pages, LaTeX: structured text with logical markup) I do not expect that you will get anything more than a document that compiles and looks similar to the pdf. PDF annotation programs usually are able to add plain text, but do not know how to handle LaTeX markup.

Comment: IMHO, these are two separate questions. Please familiarize yourself with the format of this website. Normally I would kindly ask you topmost your second question in a separate thread but it already has an answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/how-can-i-superimpose-latex-tex-output-over-a-pdf-file