# Tikzpicture as background to pdfpages

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, pdfpages, backgrounds

I want to implement the answer here: [Can I add tikzpictures to pages included with pdfpages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12838/can-i-add-tikzpictures-to-pages-included-with-pdfpages). But I want the tikzpicture under the included pdf pages, not over it. Is there a straightforward way to set what is drawn first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

As cyberSingularity mentions my original answer was wrong. I just used `background` package with the idea that it adds tikzpictures to background. It does it, but not when page contents is defined by `pdfpages`. Why?

Because `pdfpages` package uses `eso-pic`'s `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` command to print its composition so, `pdfpages` result are also printed in background.

Therefore, a better solution could be to also use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` command for printing our tikzpicture. Something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[minimum width=5cm, minimum height=5cm, font=\Huge,
              circle, draw=red, ultra thick, opacity=1, fill=pink, text=red] 
              at (current page.center) {???};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,]{blind}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Next detail shows that tikzpicture (red question marks and pink background) is behind included pdfpages as OP wanted.

[image]

**Wrong answer**

A little example with [`background`](http://ctan.org/pkg/background) package. There are some other packages in [CTAN](http://ctan.org) which can put some background to every or selected pages: watermark, wallpaper, xwatermark, ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=3,
angle=0,
contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]\node[minimum width=3cm,minimum height=3cm,font=\Huge,circle,draw,ultra thick] {?};\end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2]{blind}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cyberSingularity You're right. I'll have to look more carefully  but looks like `pdfpages` prints the result in background and anything else is added over it, even `watermark` is printed over `pdfpages`.

Comment: @cyberSingularity I think I've found a better solution. Thank you for advertising the mistake.